# How do equality proofs work mathematically?

Tags: rust, token-2022

What exactly is the math behind equality proofs in confidential transfers? Like if I can get an idea of how equality proofs work with ciphertexts.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to read through the confidential token documentation, which provides all of the required proofs and further documentation.

Here's the documentation on the equality proofs: https://spl.solana.com/confidential-token/deep-dive/zkps#equality-proof and the underlying whitepaper: https://spl.solana.com/assets/files/equality_proof-c6a1d284e7c945c6fbef90929cf852d7.pdf